# File size increases after adding digital signature

Tags: java, digital-ocean, pkcs#11, e-token

I am signing the pdfs using the usb e-token, using the PKCS11 module in my java code. The size of the document increases from 50kb to 2mb. As i understand this is happening because of the CRL (Certificate Revocation List) that is added to the document when signing. Is there any way i can avoid adding this list or avoid the size of my file increasing.

Comment: You want to avoid the size of a file increasing when you add stuff to it?

Answer (score 0):

CRLs are added not always,  this depends on signing format (if you use PAdES or not). Another possibility of the observed behaviour is that the library inserts empty placeholder for the data but does not write the data itself.  Check both of these cases in your code.

Comment: can you please suggest how can i check the second.

Comment: @ace I don't know which library you use,  so I can't tell you,  sorry.

Comment: I am using BouncyCastle.

Comment: @Ace Check its sources then.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the professionals and stakeholders are facing a problem of increasing PDF file size at the time of filing MCA & LLP form such as AOC-4, LLP Form 11 etc.  Mos of us have faced problem of increasing PDF file size after signing with Digital signature. In the case of LLP return filing, we may have to affix 4 DSC ie two partner, one designated partner and one professional DSC. each time when we affix Digital signature file size is getting increased which generally cross the size of the file prescribed by MCA for form upload.
Main reason for increasing the file size is the certificate revocation list(CRL) gets embedded with the signature each time when we affix signature.
To overcome above problem one has to follow below step

> Open any PDF file
>   go to Edit -> Preferences- > Security
>   click on Advanced Preferences, then select the ‘Creation’ tab.
>   De-select ‘Include signature’s revocation status when signing

Comment: The question is about signing in Java with BouncyCastle. Acrobat settings are in no way related to the question.